# Laravel 7 conditional form method POST | PUT

Tags: php, methods, laravel-blade, ternary, laravel-7

Hi I'm using Laravel 7 and trying to submit based on the following condition:

> if `isset($category) == true` then the method should be **PUT** 
>   if `isset($category) == false` then method should change to **POST**

Update method which is **PUT** works fine with a response *302 changed from POST to PUT*. The problem is if I'm going to submit via *POST method* based on given condition it says:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   **The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:GET, HEAD, POST.**

Any suggestion how to do it, in the same form?

Here my codes:

```
<form action="{{ isset($category) ? route('categories.update',$category->id) : route('categories.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ isset($category) ? $category->name : '' }}">
        </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">
        {{ isset($category) ? 'Update category' : 'Add category' }}
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I'm using ***Route::resource('categories','CategoriesController');***

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                        | Name               | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST      | categories                 | categories.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@store                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories                 | categories.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@index                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/create          | categories.create  | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@create                       | web          |
|        | DELETE    | categories/{category}      | categories.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@destroy                      | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | categories/{category}      | categories.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@update                       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/{category}      | categories.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@show                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/{category}/edit | categories.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@edit                         | web          |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Show your route.

Comment: I'm using resource: 
Route::resource('categories','CategoriesController');

Comment: Can you try `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:cache`?

Comment: Done running those commands. still got same error. See here: https://prnt.sc/rjqy1d

Comment: What happens if you manually add this route?

Comment: Do you mean if I'm not using resource route? Would be the same error. I was thinking probably the way I plot the conditions in form method it fails to switch back to POST request. I'm referring to these tags: `<form action="{{ isset($category) ? route('categories.update',$category->id) : route('categories.store') }}" method="POST">`  and   `@method('PUT')`

Comment: They look fine to me. Do you have a git repo of this?

Comment: Yes I do have. Here: https://github.com/KLebadesos/codecms/blob/master/resources/views/categories/create.blade.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to condition the `@method('PUT')` as well like below:

```
<form action="{{ isset($category) ? route('categories.update',$category->id) : route('categories.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @if(isset($category))
       @method('PUT')
    @endif
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ isset($category) ? $category->name : '' }}">
        </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">
        {{ isset($category) ? 'Update category' : 'Add category' }}
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It works, I see where it fails. Thank you. Since we knew that HTML forms only accept POST | GET . Is there any way to simplify the codes?  Because everytime I needed to use other method, I declare another `@method('PUT')`, `@method('DELETE')`... etc. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Kevin This is the most simplified. If you want a route to follow multiple HTTP verbs, you can use `Route::match` syntax.

Comment: Thank you! will check that out. `Route::match` ^_^